# Can anyone explain me this code in c# for SharePoint

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I was wondering if anyone could explain me the following code what it does.

```
SPWebApplication webApp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;

SPList taskList = webApp.Sites[0].RootWeb.Lists["MyList"];

SPListItemCollection taskListItems = taskList.Items;
```

and the following 2 constructor what do they do?

```
public CustomTimerJob() : base() { }
        public CustomTimerJob(string jobName, SPService service) :
            base(jobName, service, null, SPJobLockType.None)
        {
            // |Emri i job timer
            this.Title = "Task Complete Timer";
        }
        public CustomTimerJob(string jobName, SPWebApplication webapp) :
            base(jobName, webapp, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase)
        {
            this.Title = "Task Complete Timer";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SPWebApplication webApp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;

SPList taskList = webApp.Sites[0].RootWeb.Lists["MyList"];

SPListItemCollection taskListItems = taskList.Items;
```

Above code means you are accessing `MyList` from where you are running your timer job. Assuming that the `URL` of your web application host and root site collection is same. If you wish to access `MyList` from another site collection, then use following code.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("Your Site URL"))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPList taskList = web.Lists["MyList"];
                        SPListItemCollection taskListItems = taskList.Items;
                    }
                }
```

**Rest of the code explanation**

```
public CustomTimerJob() : base() { }
        public CustomTimerJob(string jobName, SPService service) :
            base(jobName, service, null, SPJobLockType.None)
        {
            // |Emri i job timer
            this.Title = "Task Complete Timer";
        }
        public CustomTimerJob(string jobName, SPWebApplication webapp) :
            base(jobName, webapp, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase)
        {
            this.Title = "Task Complete Timer";
        }
```

Learn more about timer job's constructors from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406686(v=office.12).aspx)

> The first step in creating a custom timer job is to create a class
>   that inherits from SPJobDefinition. The SPJobDefinition class contains
>   three overridden constructors. According to the Windows SharePoint
>   Services 3.0 SDK, the constructor that has no parameters is reserved
>   for internal use. The other two constructors set the timer job's name,
>   the parent Web application or service (such as the search indexer),
>   the server, and the job lock type. The lock type helps prevent
>   multiple jobs from running at the same time. There are three different
>   types of locking, as defined by the SPJobLockType enumeration:

- **SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase**   Locks the content database. A timer
  job runs one time for each content database that is associated with
  the Web application.
- **SPJobLockType.Job**   Locks the timer job so that    it runs on only one machine in the farm.
- **SPJobLockType.None**   No    locks. The timer job runs on every machine on which the parent    service is provisioned.

Comment: `SPWebApplication webApp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;

SPList taskList = webApp.Sites[0].RootWeb.Lists["MyList"];

SPListItemCollection taskListItems = taskList.Items;`
on this stage I am referring to spwebapplication. but can i do jobtimer to work also in spsitecollection so referring to spsitecollection not spswebapplication?

Comment: Yes. you can refer any site over here. In that case, approach is different.

Comment: how it is handle in this case all i need to change are these 3 lines of code, but im not sure
`SPWebApplication webApp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication; SPList taskList = webApp.Sites[0].RootWeb.Lists["MyList"]; SPListItemCollection taskListItems = taskList.Items;`
can you tell me what i have to do briefly

Comment: can you tell me briefly how to do it?

Comment: You want to access list from another site, right?

Comment: Code snippet updated. have a look

Comment: Welcome! add me in your skype. my id: du.atish@outlook.com